# AutoScaling for a Marketplace Product on Google GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to AutoScaling a product that is in the Marketplace in Google GCP, but there is no such setting. What should I do for this. If it is done with Snapshot, how does Marketplace charge? For example, I will run 3 instances. Thank you in advance for your information.

Answer (score 0):

I that is some opensource marketplace solution and does not requires licensing then you can go with the Autoscaling in GCP (UIG or MIG) with Load balancer at front end .. for example you can use WordPress in HA mode using this, the link provides good doc on this:
https://saturncloud.io/blog/autoscaler-and-http-load-balancing-with-wordpress-application-on-google-cloud/